# Problems with changing constructor's prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm currently going through Stoyan Stefanov's book "Object-oriented JavaScript" and I've stumbled on an interesting problem. Here's the code:

```
var shape = {
    type: 'shape',
    getType: function() {
        return this.type;
    }
};

function Triangle(a, b, c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.type = 'triangle';
}

Triangle.prototype = shape; // changing the prototype object
Triangle.prototype.getPerimeter = function() {
    return this.a + this.b + this.c;
}

var t = new Triangle(1, 2, 3);
t.constructor; // logs Object() instead of Triangle(a, b, c)
```

As you can see, here is a simple example of the constructor inhereting some properties from the prototype object. But the constructor property of object t points to the Object() object instead of Triangle(a, b, c), as it should have. If I comment the line with the prototype change, though, everything works fine. What's my problem?
(Reread the whole prototype chapter in Object-oriented Javascript and JavaScript Patterns, couldn't find an answer).
P.S. Sorry for my bad English, trying to practice it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will explain your code in two parts. Firstly, what is the `constructor` property actually? Secondly, why doesn't it return `Objects` in your code?

### The `constructor` property and Stoyan's mistake:

In Stoyan Stefanov's book, p150, he states:

> prototype is a property that gets created as soon as you define the function. **Its initial value is an empty object.**

It is **wrong**. According to the [JavaScript Definitive Guide](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FJavaScript-Definitive-Guide-David-Flanagan%2Fdp%2F0596000480&ei=exbOTuT0BOOeiAfise3KDg&usg=AFQjCNGs-ojUWdy5Z3PkMIwF0I_S84nbVQ&sig2=KTC2FzGBIsMNon93f9F8Uw) Section 9.2

> The initial value of the prototype property is an object **with a single property**. **This property is named constructor** and refers back to the constructor function with which the prototype is associated.

You can test it with `Triangle.prototype.constructor`. It has been set when the function is defined.

**Conclusion 1**: the `constructor` is in fact the property of `Constructor.prototype`. In your case, it is `Triangle.prototype.constructor`.

All the instances of `Triangle` could access this property through the prototype chain. **But these objects themselves don't have the `constructor` property**. The following code proves it:

```
function Triangle(a, b, c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.type = 'triangle';
}
var t = new Triangle(1, 2, 3);
t.hasOwnProperty('constructor');
>>false
t.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('constructor');
>>true
```

**Conclusion 2**: when you access the `constructor` property of an instance, you get them from the prototype chain.

### Why is it not working as you expected

You set `Triangle.prototype` to `shape` which **doesn't** contain the original`constructor` property.

Thus, this time, when you query `t.constructor`, it will resolve it in the following process:

1. Look at it's own properties and find no `constructor`
2. Keep looking up to `t.__proto__`, which is `Triangle.prototype`. You have set it to `shape` which doesn't contain the `constructor` property.
3. Continue looking up along the prototype chain - `t.__proto__.__proto__`. It is `Triangle.prototype.__proto__`, and it is resolved as `Object.prototype`. `Object.prototype` has the `constructor` property and it refers to `Object`.

Comment: __proto__ is hidden property, not defined in js specification and can be not supported. It is unsafe to use it.

Answer (score 3):

The "constructor" property, oddly enough, does not refer to the constructor of that object. Rather, it refers to the constructor of the object's prototype.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) is the relevant doc page from Mozilla.

Comment: Of course, how could I've forgot reading about it. Should have more practice instead of reading. :)

Answer (score 1):

`shape` is an object, so by doing this:

```
Triangle.prototype = shape;
```

You change `Triangle` constructor to `Object`

Answer (score 1):

You are basically using native/class based inheritance in your example here.
In Javascript, ( well from my understanding) when you use the `new` keyword you create a function object with a constructor and an attached prototype object.

When you do this:

```
Triangle.prototype = shape;
```

You override the constructor method. You can use the console to observe the objects before and after your assignment of shape to `Triangle.prototype`.

When you then do this:

```
t.constructor;
```

You are unable to view what you expect to see as the call to the constructor method finds the constructor method way down in the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

shape is not a constructor function, but an object. It's constructor is the Object constructor.

If shape was a constructor you could set

Triangle.prototype=new shape;

and Triangle.prototype.constructor=Triangle, to override the shape.prototype.constructor you just set.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var shape = {
    type: 'shape',
    getType: function () {
        return this.type
    }
}

function Triangle(a, b, c) {
    this.type = 'triangle'
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

Triangle.prototype = shape;
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;
Triangle.prototype.getPerimeter = function () {
    return this.a + this.b + this.c
}
var t = new Triangle(1, 2, 3)
console.log(t.constructor === Triangle) // true
console.log(shape.isPrototypeOf(t)) // true
console.log(t.getPerimeter()) // 6
console.log(t.getType()) // triangle
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.