# Why does an object's constructor property changes if constructor's prototype is changed?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

In the following code, taken from [Helephant.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192921/problems-with-changing-constructors-prototype), If I set's a constructor's prototype `Cat.prototype = new Pet()` to that of another object (of `Pet`) then why does it modifies the constructor of it's object `rufus.constructor` ?

`constructor` represents the function that created it. How can parent be modifiable the created it?

```
//PET CONSTRUCTOR
function Pet(name, species, hello) 
{   this.name = name;
    this.species = species;
    this.hello = hello; }

//CAT CONSTRUCTOR
function Cat(name, hello, breed, whiskerLength)
{   this.name = name;
    this.hello = hello;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.whiskerLength = whiskerLength;}

//SETTING CAT's PROTOTYPE to A NEW PET OBJECT.  
Cat.prototype = new Pet();

//CREATING A NEW CAT OBJECT
var rufus= new Cat("rufus", "miaow", "Maine Coon", 7);

//CALLING CAT OBJ's CONSTRUCTOR PROPERTY
rufus.constructor;

//OUTPUT
function Pet(name, species, hello) 
{   
this.name = name;
this.species = species;
this.hello = hello; }
```

Is it a glitch by design. Can anyone explain this behavior. What benefits does it bring?

Comment: since you have replaced the `Cat` constructor function's prototype with an object created by `new Pet()` the `rufus.constructor` is now available at `rufus.__proto__.prototype` and directs to the `Pet` constructor function.

Comment: @Redu, I think it's `rufus.__proto__.__proto__`. Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `rufus.constructor`, JavaScript checks whether there is such property on `rufus` object. It's not there, because you didn't create it there. Then it goes upwards through prototype chain and finds this property on `rufus.__proto__.__proto__` which points at `Pet` function and this function is outputted.

Here is more detailed explanation. When you declare a function:

`function Pet() { /* ..code.. */ }`

The interpreter creates the new function object from your declaration. Together with the function, it’s `prototype` property is created and populated. This default value the `prototype` is an object with property `constructor`, which is set to the function itself. In our case, to `Pet`:

`Pet.prototype = { constructor: Pet}`

This object becomes the `.__proto__` of `new Pet()` and is reachable from `rufus` by `rufus.__proto__.__proto__`. And this is exactly the object from which the `constructor` property is read:

```
rufus.hasOwnProperty('constructor') // false;    
Object.getPrototypeOf(rufus).hasOwnProperty('constructor') // false;    
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(rufus)).hasOwnProperty('constructor') // true
```

This is exactly the reason why you'll see the creation of `constructor` property on the child objects on many examples of inheritance in JavaScript:

```
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Pet.prototype); // it's better to use this instead of new Pet()
Cat.prototype.constructor = Pet;
```

Comment: `function person(fname, lname){
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
}

var i = new person("raj","kalia");
i.hasOwnProperty('constructor'); // false

Does this mean, that

Comment: `function person(fname, lname){ this.fname = fname; this.lname = lname; } var i = new person("raj","kalia"); i.hasOwnProperty('constructor'); // false 
person.hasOwnProperty('constructor'); // false` Does this mean that constructor is never a property of function object or regular objects ?

Comment: unless you create it there. the only thing that JS does for you is putting this property onto the object accessible from `.prototype` property of the function you declare. since this object later becomes the `prototype` of newly created object, this statement returns `true` -  `Object.getPrototypeOf(i).hasOwnProperty('constructor')`

Comment: @bTech, consider accepting my answer if it answers your question

Comment: Pls wait a bit btw, that's a gr8 answer

Comment: @bTech, yeah, sure, just wanted to let you know such functionality exists)

Comment: Accepted, Your answer was really good so I had to accept even if you'd asked or not. Can you plz take a look at [this related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013207/how-function-resolution-in-prototype-chain-will-work-for-object-prototype-as-con#) which is a kind of related to this. Thanks

Comment: @bTech, I gave the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40044531/2545680).

Answer (score 0):

Maxim already answered it. Yet, if want to get `Cat(...)` as the constructor of `rufus`, you may like to append another line to your code- 
`Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat`