# How function resolution in prototype chain will work for Object.prototype as constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, prototype-chain

I am referring to [this web archive of an article originally on Helephant.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20190608143204/http://helephant.com/2009/08/17/javascript-prototype-chaining/), to learn how Javascript resolves functions in the prototype chain when called on objects.

The article quotes,

> If the object doesn’t have the method set directly on it, javascript then looks for a Constructor function that created the object. Javascript checks the constructor’s prototype property for the method.

In the following code, if you check `rufus.constructor` is the global `Object()` constructor, so will JS directly check the global Object() since `rufus.constructor` is `Object()` or as per the article quote above it will first look at the constructor and then find the prototype property and so on.. How will JS resolve the function (`rufus.toString`). I am quite confused with this.

```
  //PET CONSTRUCTOR
function Pet(name, species, hello)
 
  {   this.name = name;
      this.species = species;
      this.hello = hello; }
 
Pet.prototype = {
  sayHello : function(){
    alert(this.hello);
  }
}
 
//CAT CONSTRUCTOR
  function Cat(name, hello, breed, whiskerLength)
  {   this.name = name;
      this.hello = hello;
      this.breed = breed;
      this.whiskerLength = whiskerLength;}
  
Cat.prototype = new Pet();
var rufus = new Cat("rufus", "miaow", "Maine Coon", 7);

rufus.toString;
```

Comment: is there still anything unclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the object doesn’t have the method set directly on it, javascript
>   then looks for a Constructor function that created the object.
>   Javascript checks the constructor’s prototype property for the method.

The wording is confusing. The JavaScript looks up the prototype chain through `__proto__` and **does not** use `constructor` property. They mentioned `Constructor`  because usually, that is how objects get their prototype - through `Constructor.prototype` property. But that is not always true. You can set the prototype like this:

```
var rufus2 = Object.create(new Pet());
Object.getPrototypeOf(rufus) === Object.getPrototypeOf(rufus2); // true
```

Regarding how the `toString` method is resolved:

```
                    rufus.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // false -> go up
(new Pet())         rufus.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // false -> go up 
({sayHello :...})   rufus.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // false -> go up 
(Object.prototype)  rufus.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // true
```

Comment: @Maximums, are you sure that JS does not, in-fact never use `constructor` property to find properties/methods. I'd like to believe  that it should not require to lookup the constructor property when every object has a direct pointer/path( via __proto__) to its inheritance class however, the author, IMHO is quite knowledgeable, judging by reading all her articles.

Comment: @Maximums, further reading that article she states 
> In mozilla based browsers each object exposes another property called __proto__ that gives you access to the way that the browser tracks the prototype chaining.

Comment: Does that mean, that post  illustrates 2 different ways used by browsers to resolve properties and methods. Mozilla based browsers via(__proto__) and other browsers (IE and webkit based) as how she described via `constructor` property lookup.

Comment: Further on Mozilla's [`__proto__` page] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) states >> Only recently, the __proto__ property has been standardized in the ECMAScript 6 language specification for web browsers>> so does that mean, what she wrote about property/methods lookup using 'constructor' property route, she specifically refers to older browsers sans Mozilla based browsers i.e. all older IE and webkit based browsers.

Comment: note, the article was is very old, written on `17 Aug 09`.

Comment: @bTech, the article itself is correct. It just uses confusing wording in the quote you posted. **It does not say that JS uses `.constructor` property of the object**. It says that JS checks constructor's prototype, and this is exactly what I wrote in my answer. However, since in OOP approach this prototype is usually linked to an object through its constructor function, the author decided to put that fact into explanation. It doesn't contradict what I say.

Comment: what's important for me is understanding how is the path looked-up and that is via `__proto__` on objects in the chain all the way up if required. Correct?

Comment: @bTech, yes, exactly. This link to prototype just happens to be stored in `__proto__` property, which wasn't made public before ECMAScript 6. But this link always existed there. You don't actually need to know where this link is kept. You can use `Object.getPrototype` and `Object.setPrototype` methods now.

Comment: thanks maximum for being such a huge help with your spot-on answers. Following u on Medium

Comment: @bTech, you're welcome. I remember myself trying to wrap my head around all this stuff. It's a good habit to try to understand the matter deep down to details. Good luck with your learning)

Comment: If you set `prototype.constructor` properties to `null` ANYWHERE in the prototype chain, you can still resolve to functions set on referenced functions prototype. The comment "If the object doesn’t have the method set directly.." i not only misleading it's just wrong since a `Constructor` isn't actually a thing in JavaScript. Any function (defined with the `function` keyword) can be used as a `Constructor`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person () { }
Person.prototype.sayName = function () { };


var bob = new Person();
console.log(bob.sayName === Person.prototype.sayName); // true
console.log(bob.constructor.prototype.sayName === Person.prototype.sayName); // true
console.log(bob.__proto__.sayName === Person.prototype.sayName); // true


console.log(bob.constructor === Person); // true
console.log(bob.__proto__ === Person.prototype); // true
```

Those are your relationships.
If a property / function can not be found on an object, it goes up the `__proto__` chain to find what it's looking for. In older browsers, `__proto__` was not accessible to JS devs, but was still the object that the browser/Node used behind the scenes, to refer to the Constructor.prototype property.

PS: try not to use deep hierarchy in JS. That is a path of many tears. Deep hierarchies cause pain in other class-based languages, but are misery in JS, where often a function would suffice.

Comment: Can you pls try answering in the context of the code I posted, the object (`rufus`)inherits from object (`Cat.prototype = new Pet()`)of another type (`Pet`), whose prototype `Pet.prototype` itself inherits from global `Object.prototype` (`{}`). In your code, the constructor and prototype objects are quite obvious and is little help in understanding where the inheritance in much more complex inheritance structures, as in my case.